# Powershell script works on server but not with cloudformation cfn-init functions

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cloud-init

I have to set windows ec2 servers through cloudformation script.
I have some powershell script which add label and format the disk drives in specific format.

The problem is when this powershell script get called from cloudformation cfn functions it gives error like (from LOGS)

```
a-label-format-drives-sql output: At C:\cfn\scripts\Label-and-Format-drives.ps1:44 char:35
+     $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
+                                   ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\cfn\scripts\Label-and-Format-drives.ps1:36 char:5
+     {
+     ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At C:\cfn\scripts\Label-and-Format-drives.ps1:27 char:19
+   $LablenFormatPs={
+                   ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At C:\cfn\scripts\Label-and-Format-drives.ps1:19 char:5
+ try {
+     ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At C:\cfn\scripts\Label-and-Format-drives.ps1:64 char:1
+ 
The Try statement is missing its Catch or Finally block.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

But when the same script is directly run in powershell console in same windows ec2 it runs perfectly fine. I have this poweshell script uploaded in to s3 bucket and I am fetching it in cloudformation and saving it on ec2 instances.

Here is my complete script. https://gist.github.com/rturam/c969e161b4089ac62d89b8ba5d1d1612

Comment: What does log show ?

Comment: its pasted in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue myself. There was a problem with copy-paste from website to editor. While pasting there was some strange characters come along and were not viewable in an editor. 
The trick is just doing `cat <file_name>` in PowerShell CLI. It will show the foreign characters if any.